# SQL71561: SqlComputedColumn: When column selected

Tags: sql-server, database, dacpac, azure-data-studio

Required to access the view from different source database.
I am using the Azure data studio with SQL Database project. First I've exported Source database into dacpac and in new project created the Database reference point to source dacpac.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_activitypointer] AS
SELECT  *  FROM  [$(dvdbname)].[dbo].[ap_partitioned];
GO
```

It's working with above statement using * all column and it's able  to build and depoly the project successfully. Instead of all columns, I need few columns when I change to specify column it's failing with SQL71561: SqlComputed column error

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_activitypointer] AS
SELECT  [ucode]  FROM  [$(dvdbname)].[dbo].[ap_partitioned];
GO
```

```
c:\dbt\cicdtest\v_activitypointer.sql(2,13,2,13):
Build error SQL71561: SqlView: [dbo].[v_activitypointer] has an unresolved reference to object [$(dvdbname)].[dbo].[ap_partitioned].[ucode]. [c:dbtcicdtestcicdtest.sqlproj]

c:dbtcicdtestv_activitypointer.sql(2,13,2,13):
Build error SQL71561: SqlComputedColumn: [dbo].[v_activitypointer].[ucode] has an unresolved reference to object [$(dvdbname]).[dbo].[ap_partitioned].[ucode]. [c:dbtcicdtestcicdtest.sqlproj]

stdout:     0 Warning(s)
stdout:     2 Error(s)
```

Here's .sqlproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build">
    <Sdk Name="Microsoft.Build.Sql" Version="0.1.12-preview" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Name>cicdtest</Name>
        <ProjectGuid>{25E6C2C6-1C07-4516-BDC0-06E5AF0DCE07}</ProjectGuid>
        <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlServerlessDatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
        <ModelCollation>1033, CI</ModelCollation>
        <VerificationExtract>false</VerificationExtract>
        <VerifyExtendedTransactSQLObjectName>False</VerifyExtendedTransactSQLObjectName>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <SqlCmdVariable Include="dvdbname">
            <Value>$(SqlCmdVar__1)</Value>
            <DefaultValue>dataverse_uunq6705</DefaultValue>
        </SqlCmdVariable>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ArtifactReference Include="..\dataverse_uunq6705.dacpac">
            <SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>False</SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
            <DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>dataverse_uunq6705</DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>
        </ArtifactReference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Delete Files="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)\project.assets.json" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I tried turning off the VerificationExtract & VerifyExtendedTransactSQLObjectName but no use.

Comment: Hint: `$(dvdbname)`